# Inequality in $L^2$ involving integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Exercise 32. chapter 6. from Folland

> Suppose that $(X, \mathcal{M}, \eta)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N}, \nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $K\in L^2(\eta\otimes\nu)$. If $f\in L^2(\nu)$, the integral 
>   $$
>   Tf(x) =\int_Y K(x,y)f(y)d\nu
> $$ 
>   converges absolutely for a.e. $x \in X$; moreover, $T f \in L^2(\eta)$ and $\|Tf\|_2\leq \|K\|_2\|f\|_2$.

I can't find a way to apply previous results to this. For example since $\infty>\int K^2 d(\eta\times \nu)=\int\int K^2 d\eta d\nu$ can I conclude $\int |K|d\eta,\ \int |K| d\nu<\infty$ for a.e. x, y? If so by some previous result $||Tf||_2\leq C||f||_2$, where $C$ is common bound for $\int |K|d\eta,\ \int |K| d\nu$. But I would then like $C$ to be $||K||_2$, an I cannot establish connection  $\int |K| d\eta,\ \int |K| d\nu\leq \left[\int K^2 d(\eta\times\nu)\right]^2$

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Then by given help I've managed so far: $||Tf||_2=\left[\int\left(\int K(x, y)f(y)d\nu(y)\right)^2d\eta(x)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq$ **can I apply Cauchy-Schwarz now?** $\leq \left[\int\left(||K(x,\cdot)||_2||f||_2\right)^2d\eta(x)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=||f||_2\left[\int ||K(x,\cdot)||_2^2d\eta(x)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=||f||_2\left[\int \int K(x,y)^2d\nu(y)d\eta(x)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=||f||_2||K||_2$

Where do I need $\sigma$ finite?

Comment: What about applying Cauchy-Shwartz? Also, in Folland he often uses the trick of proving something for finite measures, and then using this result for $\sigma$-finite ones.

Comment: I think that you also have to use Fubini theorem in some step.

Comment: Ali za dokaz integralne Minkowski nejednakosti se koristi Holder i Fubinijeva teorema. Samo kazem. Valjda mi nece zameriti sto ovako pisem. Lep pozdrav za tebe :-)

Cas vidim, cas ne vidim tvoj komentar. Ne znam sta se dogadja. Nije ni bitno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $\sigma$-finiteness assumption is quite contained in the fact that the kernel $K$ is square integrable. We can indeed restrict ourselves to the subset where this kernel does not vanish, and notice that this can be written as a countable union of sets of finite measure.

Here, we just need to deal with non-negative functions, and it could be convenient to switch the integrals, even if it's maybe not needed for these questions (but maybe for the following).